# Facebook social login page is loading off centre

Tags: javascript, facebook, popupwindow

I'm launching a popup for Facebook social login.

But when connecting to Facebook the "https://facebook.com/login/reauth.php" page is loaded off centre. Therefore half the form and the "continue" button are hidden from the user.

This is what Facebook looks like when it loads (off centre): https://imgur.com/a/dxhjSfA

But I need it to load like this (centred in the popup): https://imgur.com/a/n8Swqs2

How can I make it centred?

This is what I'm using to launch the popup. It launches in the centre of the opening window, but I can't make the Facebook page that is loaded be centred in popup:

```
let windowObjectReference = null;
let previousUrl = null;

const openSignInWindow = (url, name) => {

    // remove any existing event listeners
    window.removeEventListener('message', receiveMessage);

    // window features (open in center of opening window - works well for multi monitor setups)
    const w = '600';
    const h = '700';
    const y = window.outerHeight / 2 + window.screenY - ( h / 2);
    const x = window.outerWidth / 2 + window.screenX - ( w / 2);
    const strWindowFeatures =
        `toolbar=no, menubar=no, width=${w}, height=${h}, top=${y}, left=${x}`;

    if (windowObjectReference === null || windowObjectReference.closed) {
        /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
         or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */
        windowObjectReference = window.open(url, name, strWindowFeatures);
    } else if (previousUrl !== url) {
        /* if the resource to load is different,
         then we load it in the already opened secondary window and then
         we bring such window back on top/in front of its parent window. */
        windowObjectReference = window.open(url, name, strWindowFeatures);
        windowObjectReference.focus();
    } else {
        /* else the window reference must exist and the window
         is not closed; therefore, we can bring it back on top of any other
         window with the focus() method. There would be no need to re-create
         the window or to reload the referenced resource. */
        windowObjectReference.focus();
    }

    // add the listener for receiving a message from the popup
    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

    // assign the previous URL
    previousUrl = url;

};
```

Comment: There used to be a parameter named `display` for the login dialog call, that could be set to `popup` to make it adapt to smaller windows - but it appears to have gone from the documentation. You could try if it still works; if not, then maybe simply say goodbye to popups with custom dimensions, and just open it in a normal new tab. (Popups with custom dimensions specified by the site author are a bit of an anachronism anyway, modern user-friendly browsers allow to override such choices these days. My browser is set to _never_ open custom sized popups, but always full tabs.)

Comment: That worked! Thanks